# Is it a good practice to have both MobX and setState in one application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm trying to understand the principle of global state management in react applications.

In my recent ReactJS project, I've encountered a situation where having a global state would be a better choice, but I only need this for a few components. All other components have its own state, and I'm just using `setState()` method there.

So my question is... would it be beneficial to refactor the entire app and use MobX everywhere or it is okay to use it only where necessary?

I'm worried about code quality and I want to manage my application in a "correct way".

Sorry if this question sounds stupid but I'd be really glad if you can help me. Thank you.

Comment: It is okay to use it only where necessary, think about it, you want a simple state for some `button`, useState is more "close" to the component than any other state manager. State manager's job is to avoid "boiltrap" code for nested states, using the state manager is an overkill.

Comment: If you need this for a few components, even consider not using MobX at all maybe? `Context` and `useReducer` might be a good alternative.

Comment: I'm trying not to use setState due to its async behaviour. For global stores try to use Context - it's way easier to keep store logic in other place then in every component.

But still.. I don't think there is the 'correct way' to do so. Either using Mobx/Context or setStates will do job properly I quess.